# Facebook Graphi API - How long does it take to get access for app review permission and features and also need briefing about app creation

Tags: facebook-graph-api

App Review Requests
Current requests

Pending requests: pages manage instant articles,
pages_ manage_ ads, instagram_ manage_ messages,
pages user locale, groups access member info,
instagram manage comments, instagram manage insights,
pages_ user_timezone, read_insights, pages_manage _posts,
pages manage metadata, pages user gender.
pages read user content, pages show list, instagram basic,
pages messaging, pages manage engagement,
pages _read _engagement, Page Mentions, Instagram Public Content
Access, embed Read, Live video API, Page Public Metadata
Access, Page Public Content Access, Human Agent

Comment: 1 day to never. Those are a lot a permission in one request and your video needs to show you need access to each one and how it will be used. I suggest doing only a few permission requests at a time.

Comment: @GeoffreyBourne okay I have another query is it compulsory that you should have a website or app for getting the permissions and features required for data extraction.

Comment: Yes, you need an app/website - since you need to show a video of the OAuth and functionality.

Comment: @GeoffreyBourne Thank you for taking the time to reply for my query.